# How do i check what android version my react native can support?

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native: 0.63.0.

How do i check what is the minimum android and ios version is required to use my apps?

Thanks you

Comment: Any android version is supported which is higher than 4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the latest react native doc,

```
React Native apps may target iOS 10.0 and Android 4.1 (API 16) or newer
```

previously, for ios minimum supported version was iOS 7+

But I'm not sure it will work for less than iOS 10.0 as most of the iphones have iOS 10+

Please find more info in this doc [react-native requirements](https://github.com/facebook/react-native#-requirements)

Answer (score 3):

React Native supports all Android versions higher than 4.1 (API 16).

So inside the **project/build.gradle** you can check :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
   
    }
```

**minSdkVersion = 16** , so minSDKverison describes the lowest level android api supported .Hence its 16, so **android 4.1**

Hope it helps. feel free for douts